# Django endless pagination in cms page

Tags: django, django-cms, django-endless-pagination

How can i show django endless pagianation in a django cms page ? currently i am rendering my content(images) using template tag. Is it possible to write the pagination code in template tag ?.
my cms template is:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags instagram_images media_list %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block main_content %}
<section class="bigBanner clearfix">
    <div class="container "> </div>
</section>
</div>
</section>
<hgroup class="title">
    <div class="container ">
        <h1>Videos</h1>
    </div>
</hgroup>
<section class="clearfix content innerPage galleyPage">
    {% get_video_gallery %}
    <hgroup class="title">
        <div class="container ">
            <h1>Images</h1>
        </div>
    </hgroup>
    <div class="container">
        {% get_photo_gallery %}
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

and my get_photo_gallery template tag is:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('cms/templatetags/image_gallery.html')
def get_photo_gallery():
    try:
        images = Images.objects.all()
    except:
        images = None
    return {'images':images}
```

my image_gallery.html is :

```
<div class="imageSelector">
    Select a category :‭ ‬<select name="" class="selector">
      <option>Events</option>
      <option>Events</option>
      <option>Events</option>
      <option class="last">Events</option>
    </select><input name="GO" type="submit" class="goBtn" id="GO" value="GO" />
  </div>

{% for image in images %}
{% if forloop.counter|add:"-1"|divisibleby:"3" %}
    <div class="clearfix row-fluid">
 {% endif %}
      <div class="span4">
        <a class="gallery" href="{{ image.image.url }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %} title="{{ image.description_ar }}" {% else %} title="{{ image.description }}" {% endif %}>
           <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" width="370 px" height="302px" alt="" /></a>
        {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
            <p>{{ image.description_ar|truncatechars:17|safe }}</p>
            {% else %}
             <p>{{ image.description|truncatechars:17|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
      </div>
  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
       </div>
        {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

What i actually want to show is twitter style pagination http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html .The normal pagination works since its only template changes to show the paginated page.But twitter style requires changes in view and cms page template is not rendered using a view.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html